# How PHP Login(system) Sessions work Loading logged in user's data from the database?

Tags: php, session, permissions

I need to create an internal (for my company use only) website and I really need to understand how the login system or session works. I have done a lot of search online but still don't quite understand how to load a logged in user's data based on his permissions. For example there will be an Admin Panel where you can create a user and assign some permissions such as for example: while logged in to the website, a user can have access to some information and/or can change some settings of a layout but not all of the settings and it is based on his permissions. I hope you understand what I am trying to ask you! Please help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

A log in system works based on, when a user inputs their credentials (username and password, for example), the information gets sent to a page that checks it with information in a database. If the username and password match a row in the database, meaning a user exists with that username and password, then they get logged in. To set roles for users, you could have a column in the database, and each user could get a rank of say 0-10, 10 being admin, and 0 being rookie, for example, and having no permissions. On the log in page, a session, a "term" is created, in which variables are stored, such as their username, etc. These can be set and retrieved with the PHP `$_SESSION['variable_name']`. Also on that page you can retrieve the user's permission level, if there is a match for that user. If their rank is 10, then they get redirected to the `level_10.php` page, for example, or if their rank is 1, then they get redirected to the `level_1.php` page. On that page, you start the session (or resume it), and check if there is a session, or if a certain session variable is set, such as their username. If it is set, you can check their permission level with a `mysql_` or `mysqli_`. Then, if their permission is appropriate for that page, then the page prints the code. If not, they get redirected to the appropriate page. Hope this helps, and happy coding!

Comment: Thank you for your almost immediate response to my question. So basically the levels 1 to 10 or I can create groups for example 1 to 10 But you are saying that there must be 10 pages for a group level for Admin there must be an Admin page and for Rookie there must be a Rookie Page. But is there a way to generate a web page on the fly (dynamically) and show information from the database for a logged in user just based on his level of permissions ?